# How can I block access to certain web pages in Android using Xamarin.Android in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: web, xamarin.android

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and I need to block certain web pages of the smartphone, I work with Xamarin in android and the emulators that come by default in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this.

**1.Block websites through your browser**

Some browsers allow you to install add-ons. In this case we will be taking a look at a Firefox add-on. If you don’t have Firefox installed already, you can download it here. Once that’s done, all you need to block websites is to get the BlockSite add-on.

**2.Block websites with an app**

- **Google Family Link**

If you want to monitor your child’s online activity and protect them from inappropriate websites, one of your first choices should be Google Family Link. It not only allows you to block websites on Chrome, but also set limited access to certain apps and mature content on Google Play. If you want to know more about it, you can read our detailed guide on how it works [here](https://www.androidauthority.com/google-family-link-review-878088/).

- **BlockSite**

If your main goal is to stop yourself from procrastinating by blocking websites, you can once again turn to BlockSite — this time in app form. The application has an easy-to-use, clean interface that will guide you through the process of blocking websites and apps. However, what makes it great is the ability to schedule blocking, as well as its work mode that will help you stay productive.

- **Mobile Security & Antivirus**

If you want to combine online security with parental controls, you can’t go wrong with the Mobile Security & Antivirus application by Trend Micro. It’s simple to use, it blocks dangerous websites and protects you from phishing, ransomware and more. However, the parental control is a premium feature.

**3. Block websites with a firewall**

If you want to go one step further, you can block websites on Android with the help of a firewall. Most require rooting your device, but there are root-free options. One of the best says it all in its name — NoRoot Firewall. It has a clean and easy-to-use interface and requires minimal permissions.

**Note:**

For more , you can enter key words `How to block websites on Android` in your browser to find more useful article about this.

Comment: How Can I modified the Hosts field in android, Im working with xamarin forms in C#